# change the span tag for specific time

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

code :

```
<div>
 <p> Day is <span>beautiful</span></p>
</div>
```

Now I want to changing the span tag for every 5 second

For Example

**Day is beautiful**
after 5 sec
**Day is good**
then after 5 sec **Day is awesome** then again **Day is beautiful**

Means only span tag is changing for every 5 sec

I don't know how to do this

Comment: Grab yourself a variable to hold the current state and the `setInterval()` function :)

Comment: You can use an array with those strings and use `setInterval(function(){})` to loop through it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```js
var span = document.querySelector("div p span");
var words = ["good", "awesome", "beautiful"];
var index = 0;
function change() {
 index = (index + 1) % words.length;
 var word = words[index];
 span.innerText = word;
};
setInterval(change, 5000);
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Day is <span>beautiful</span></p>
</div>
```